# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de recorrer un DBF, recorre 94 registros y luego me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last): File "d:\Projects\migrarDBF\error01.py", line 31, in inserTmovim() File "d:\Projects\migrarDBF\error01.py", line 23, in
inserTmovim for record in table.records: File "C:\Users\LPAREDES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 314, in
_iter_records items = [(field.name, File "C:\Users\LPAREDES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 315, in
parse(field, read(field.length)))
File "C:\Users\LPAREDES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 79, in parse return func(field, data) File
"C:\Users\LPAREDES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 207, in parseT dt =
datetime.datetime.fromordinal(day - offset) OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comparto mi código y mi DBF (https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah_xawk5q7pCjJhKx7frsu_URsdHlQ?e=EqLUvZ).

```
from dbfread import DBF
def inserTmovim():
   table = DBF('TMOVIM.DBF')
   for record in table.records:
      print(record)
inserTmovim()
```

Comment: Básicamente es porque el valor que tienes es muy grande y excede el límite de la variable. ¿Haz verificado qué valor es el que produce ese error?

Comment: Hola, HeytalePazguato, lo que pasa es que no se como controlar ello, ya que solo estoy recorriendo el DBF, eh pensado en cambiar el tipo de dato de fechas, por que hay columnas que podrían estar involucradas, pero no se como

Comment: No se si tenga que ver, pero en el registro 96 la columna `MOVFECANUL` hay una fecha incorrecta `15/09/-06 00:00`

Comment: Eso podría ser, ya que estaría fuera del límite de la fecha. Intenta corregir el valor y hacerlo. Podrías utilizar `try` y `except` para brincar los datos que están mal y hacer un `print` del `id` por ejemplo para que al final puedas ver los valores que están mal y corregirlos

Comment: aeportugal, el error aparece en la fila 95 :'(

Comment: HeytalePazguato, en el except que colocaría para que el recorrido no paralice y salte?

Comment: Y no es el único registro, en la línea 351 en la misma columna y también en la MOVFECHREC tiene el mismo caso de fecha incorrecta. También en la 558, 1054, 1195, etc... Tendrás que modificar el parser para que detecte posibles errores en la data y los corrija. También puedes usar la herramienta de buscar por `/-` en el explorador de la BD para detectar esos errores y corregirlos a mano si quieres.

Comment: quisiera que los datos erróneos los lea como nulos, la idea es insertar estos datos en sql, pero esa tabla es no me deja ni siquiera recorrer, por eso no se como podría saltar esos datos, me podrían ayudar por favor

Comment: Los errores deben ser corregidos, no ignorados. No puedes poner información incompleta o errónea en la base de datos.

Comment: Candid Moe, tienes mucha razón pero no se como corregirlo, por eso quería que me echen una manito

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los datos vienen con errores. La única manera de descubrirlos es pasando el archivo y trabajando los problemas uno a uno.

En este caso, la ejecución produce:

```
OrderedDict([('MOVCODITIP', 'E'), ('MOVNUMERO', '080000054'), ('ALMCODIORG', '012A00'), ('ALMORGVIR', '012A0001'), ('ALMCODIDST', '012A01'), ('ALMDSTVIR', '012A0101'), ('MOVTIPODCI', '13'), ('MOVNUMEDCI', '2912'), ('MOVTIPODCO', '14'), ('MOVNUMEDCO', '1428'), ('MOVNUMEPED', None), ('MOVFECHREC', datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 17, 0, 0)), ('MOVFECHEMI', None), ('CCTCODIGO', '01'), ('CLICOD', '00000000'), ('PCTCOD', ''), ('DIAGCOD', ''), ('PROGCOD', ''), ('PERCOD', ''), ('MOVTOT', 649.96), ('PRVNUMERUC', '20100024862'), ('PRVDESCRIP', 'A TARRILLO BARBA S.A'), ('MOVREFE', '2DA ENTREGA'), ('MOVINDPRC', 'M'), ('USRCODIGO', '005'), ('MOVFECHREG', datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 29, 17, 36, 35)), ('MOVFECHULT', datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 29, 17, 36, 35)), ('MOVSITUA', '1'), ('TIP_COMP', '3'), ('TIP_PROC', '08'), ('NUM_PROC', '004-2007-DSRS-C'), ('MOVTIPEST', ''), ('MOVCODSUB', ''), ('MOVTIPREC', ''), ('MOTCOD', ''), ('FDOCOR', datetime.date(2008, 1, 7)), ('MOVFECANUL', None), ('MOVUSUANUL', ''), ('ID_PROCESO', ''), ('DNI_CLIE', ''), ('DIAGCOD1', ''), ('DIAGCOD2', ''), ('MOVENVIO', '')])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raul/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 6, in <module>
    inserTmovim()
  File "/home/raul/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 4, in inserTmovim
    for record in table.records:
  File "/home/raul/venv/micropython/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbfread/dbf.py", line 314, in _iter_records
    items = [(field.name,
  File "/home/raul/venv/micropython/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbfread/dbf.py", line 315, in <listcomp>
    parse(field, read(field.length))) \
  File "/home/raul/venv/micropython/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbfread/field_parser.py", line 79, in parse
    return func(field, data)
  File "/home/raul/venv/micropython/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbfread/field_parser.py", line 207, in parseT
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(day - offset)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum

Process finished with exit code 1
```

que me dice dos cosas:

1. El error está en la línea que sigue al movimiento `080000054`, Tipo `E`.
2. Hay una celda con un valor imposible.

Con eso me voy a la planilla y ubico el movimiento `080000054`, Tipo `E`. Esa fue la última fila correctamente leida, por lo que la culpable tiene que ser la fila 96:

[image: Planilla en la fila 96]

y si recorremos la fila 96 hasta el final, nos encontramos esto en la celda AK:

[image: Fila 96, celda AK]

El contenido es `09/15/-6206 00:00:00`, y es interpretado como una fecha, lo cual implica convertirlo a un entero que cuenta segundos desde una fecha inicial. Como la fecha está fuera de rango, se produjo un *overflow* (desborde).

Conclusión: *Garbage in, garbage out*

#### Solución

Corregir el dato, reprocesar el archivo.

El archivo tiene más errores, los que hay que tratar igual que el presente.

Comment: y hay una manera de saltarse esos datos erróneos y solo recorrer los más actuales?

Comment: Acabo de abrir el archivo DBF con Visual fox pro, pero no encuentro esa fecha que figura en el excel

Comment: No conozco DBF.